# Why are my bootstrap 4 columns stacking vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap 4. When I switched from 3 to 4, my columns didn't line up. I looked up a lot of documentation, but still can't get it to be in a row. Any help would be appreciated!! 
[before: bootstrap 3 image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUtSH.png)

[after: bootstrap 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEQyl.png)

Code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="skillsbox hvr-wobble-skew">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <h4>HTML 5</h4>
                        <img src="img/html5.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <h4>&#64;Southern Utah University</h4>
                        <img src="img/suu.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <h4>Description</h4>
                        <p>blah blah blah</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <h4>Dates</h4>
                        <p>Spring and Fall 2014</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please read the docs. *"content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows."*

Comment: It IS inside a row...

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks! I searched for an hour and never saw this thread.